# To Inline an External Function Written in Assembly

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I have a separate function written in assembly and want to call it in my C/C++ code.  Is it possible to tell my compiler (MS Visual C++ 2010) to inline that module written in assembly into my C/C++ function?

Note, I am not talking about using inline assembly code (__asm {}) in my C/C++ function.  All assembly codes are written in separate independent modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell my compiler … to inline that module written in assembly into my C/C++ function?

No. The *compiler* doesn’t even see the assembly code – it’s in a different compilation unit. You can ask your *linker* to inline the function though. In order to do that, you need to enable link-time optimizations.

There may be a separate option for the linker that tells it to perform inlining but usually this should be done automatically where it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like to be the /LTCG linker option.

Comment: @Javaman - No, that tells the linker to use **the compiler** to finish compiling after linking. It doesn't affect external assembler code.

Comment: Should I use /GL during compilation?  Looks like "Whole program optimization" would cause the compiler to look at my obj file created by my assembly src and do some cross module inlining.  Right?